# Should HTTP redirects be used to correct misleading URL's

Tags: http, url, redirect

I have some logic in an MVC controller which can result in a URL parameter being ignored leading to a URL potentially being misleading

As an illustration:

If the GET handler logic in the controller for the following URL:

http://example.com/results?sortByField=10&search=full&locationId=1

ignores the value of sortByField and calculates a value using the other parameter types

e.g.

```
   if (search="full" && locationId = 1)
   then
     //sort results by field 1
   else 
     //sort results by sortByField paramater
```

This means that the URL implies that the results are sorted by field 10 while the actual sort field is 1.

One solution to this would be to do a 302 redirect to the original URL modified to have sortByField=1 from within the if statement above. This would lead to a clean URL which reflects the behaviour of the page but results in an additional round trip and also doesn't seem to fully fit the definition of a 302 redirect.

Any thoughts on whether this even matters and the pros and cons of using a redirect appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're canonicalising URLs, 301 is the status code to use. A client that has requested:

```
http://example.com/results?sortByField=10&search=full&locationId=1
```

and been redirected to:

```
http://example.com/results?sortByField=1&search=full&locationId=1
```

should always use the second URL in future.

> Any thoughts on whether this even matters

If you're expecting your clients to examine the URLs they're using then it's a nice way to self-document. There can also be benefits for caching.

It's certainly REST-fully valid; whether the extra round-trip is worth it really depends on the performance concerns of the site you're running.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I proposed 302 since it is the internal implementation which decides to override the sortByField parameter and this _may_ change in the future.